# Animate() scroll has an unnecessary delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use both `nextButton` and `previousButton` to scroll through the 6 scenes that are on screen.

When I hit the bottom of the document and press `nextButton`, I go to the top. The other way around for `previousButton`.  So it continuously loops.

It also takes my scroll position into account, but I set overflow to `hidden` for now.

I use `animate({scrollTop})` to get the scroll effect i want, however, adding a duration to it doesn't make the animation act on that speed. It adds a delay.

if i would add, for instace `4000` next to the scrollTop function, to indicate that it should do a 4-second scroll, it will wait out those 4 seconds instead and then scroll to the next/previous scene on regular speed.

to give an example of one of the button's code :

```
$("#previousButton").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     $('.scenes').each(function() {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            prevSlide = $(this).prev();
        }
    });


//goes to last scene to create scrolling loop
    if(prevSlide.length == 0) {
  prevSlide = $('.scenes').last();
    }


        $("html, body").animate ({scrollTop: $(prevSlide).offset().top}, 10);
});
```

currently i set the duration to `10` to make sure there is minimal delay before the animation happens, but of course this isn't what I want.

What's causing this delay on how can it be fixed? or is this normal behaviour? Reason that i ask this because certain examples on w3 schools seem to animate totally fine with a set-duration, unless the changing of width/height and such is completely different compared scrollTop

[My codepen for the full code](https://codepen.io/vorkot3/pen/gObwxpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of your css `scroll-behavior:smooth;`

Remove this part and it works.

Comment: thank you! really didnt know that could be the cause.